# What is the difference between these constructions?

Tags: grammar

I just came across these four sentences on a worksheet my son is doing. We are in Japan - so this is from English class at his Japanese school.

- It’s surprising that he should be an actor.
- It’s surprising that he would be an actor.
- It’s surprising that he be an actor.
- It’s surprising that he is an actor.

My son is asking me the difference and I'm drawing a blank. In casual speech, it seems like we use all of these interchangeably and so they seem the same to me. I can feel a slight difference but I can't articulate what that difference is. And I don't know the grammar well enough to figure out what the actual difference between them is. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the question ask him to distinguish them? Also, this should be on ELU Stack Exchange.

Comment: 1 and 4 are roughly equivalent, except that 1 makes it a bit more hypothetical whether he really is an actor or not. 2 is quite odd and requires a very specific situation to be possible, e.g., “So he said that he would be an actor if could be anything he wanted? It’s surprising that he’d be an actor and not a doctor”. 3 is, as far as I can tell, completely ungrammatical and not possible in any context in current-day English. It probably worked in Jane Austen’s time, and definitely in Shakespeare’s, but subjunctives after adjectives like _surprising_ are completely dead now.